# convert a DateTime to Oracle DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, oracle11g, converters

Im looking to convert a DateTime to an Oracle DateTime  (to pass to an Oracle stored proc.)
I was thinking of using what's below in a general conversions class I have but I'm not sure how to return the converted date, could anyone kick me in the right direction?

thanks

```
public static explicit operator OracleDateTime(DateTime dt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that operator means you can just cast:

```
DateTime input = new DateTime(...);
OracleDateTime result = (OracleDateTime) input;
...
```

It's not clear what you mean by "how to return the converted date" - it's not like you'd want a method for this, given that it's already been implemented for you.

Comment: Ahh, got it.  I misunderstood the use of it.  Thanks